# find lowest x and y

Tags: php, math

I have an array of X and y coordinates, how can I find the nearest point to the 0,0 and sort them from the nearest to the farthest point from the 0,0?

```
  <?php
        $array = array(array("x" => 10,
                             "y" => 10),

                       array("x" => 120,
                             "y" => 560),

                       array("x" => 950,
                             "y" => 23),

                       array("x" => 78,
                             "y" => 40),);
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english :|

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: I agree with John, please try something, look for sorting or searching algorithms and try some implementation and if you don't find any good solution, post what you did and ask for help. This is my recommendation.

Comment: The answer depends on how you define distance, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_metric

Comment: Did you sleep through math class? `$c = sqrt(pow($a, 2) + pow($b, 2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using usort:

```
<?php
//your array
$array = array(array("x" => 10,
                     "y" => 10),

               array("x" => 120,
                     "y" => 560),

               array("x" => 950,
                     "y" => 23),

               array("x" => 78,
                     "y" => 40),);

//define a compare function
function cmp($a,$b){
    //get the squared distance of a and b
    $distA_SQ = $a['x']*$a['x']+$a['y']*$a['y'];
    $distB_SQ = $b['x']*$b['x']+$b['y']*$b['y'];

    //if squared distances are the same, return 0
    if($distA_SQ==$distB_SQ)return 0;

    //distances are not the same so return 1 if a larger than b or -1 if b larger than a
    return $distA_SQ>$distB_SQ?1:-1;
}

//run the sort function
usort($array, 'cmp');

//output the array
var_dump($array);
```

http://codepad.org/OBH1cskb

And to determine if distance of point A is greater than B, you don't need to sqrt the distance. It is expensive and unnecessary.

Edit: Added comments to code and explanation below

This uses [usort](http://www.php.net/usort), which uses a user defined compare function. usort will look over the array performing a quicksort by calling your compare function and passing in two values at a time (usually passed in as $a and $b) and expects your compare function to return -1 if $a is less than $b, 0 if $a is equal to $b or 1 if $a is greater than $b. you can read more on usort in the [manual](http://www.php.net/usort).

Comment: @Bamba added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array and put x, y and their distance from (0,0) in it.

```
$distArray = array();
foreach($distArray as $point):
$distArray[] = array($point['x'],$point['y'],dist($point['x'],$point['y']));
endforeach;
```

now sort this array by it's third element. I believe writing the dist() function would be easy.

EDIT: I suggest to keep the x and y in your array so when you sort the result array, you know which item is which point.

Comment: write dist yourself, just this https://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/154/factor/circle.htm

```
function calculateDistance($x,$y)
{
    //apply formula
    return sqrt(pow($x, 2) + pow($y, 2)); //<--Sammitch pointed out directly 
}
$data = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$distance)
{//this is better because you can have points that have the same distance
   $data[calculateDistance($distance['x'],$distance['y'])][] = $key;
}
    ksort($data);
```

RESULT

```
 in:
$array = array(array("x" => 10,
                             "y" => 10),

                       array("x" => 120,
                             "y" => 560),
                       array("x" => 120,
                             "y" => 560),
                       array("x" => 950,
                             "y" => 23),

                       array("x" => 78,
                             "y" => 40));
    output:
    array (size=4)
      14 =>  //<--key is the distance and the value are the keys from your array
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 0
      87 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 4
      572 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 2
      950 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$array = array(array("x" => 10,
                     "y" => 10),

               array("x" => 120,
                     "y" => 560),

               array("x" => 950,
                     "y" => 23),

               array("x" => 78,
                     "y" => 40),);


$distance = array();
 $req_array = array();
 foreach($array as $subArray)
{
 $distance[] = sqrt(pow(($subArray[x],2)+pow(($subArray[y],2));
}

asort($distance);

foreach($distance as $key=>$value)
{
  $req_array[] = $array[$key];
}


print_r($distance);
print_r($req_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    array("x" => 10, "y" => 10),

    array("x" => 120, "y" => 560),

    array("x" => 950, "y" => 23),

    array("x" => 78, "y" => 40)
);

$start_point_array = $array;
$end_point_array = $array;
$farthest_points = array();
$farthest_distance = 0;

foreach($start_point_array as $index => $start_point) {
    for($i = $index + 1; $i < count($end_point_array); $i++) {
        $end_point = $end_point_array[$i];
        $distance = sqrt(pow($end_point['x'] - $start_point['x'], 2) + pow($end_point['y'] - $start_point['y'], 2));
        if($distance > $farthest_distance) {
            $farthest_distance = $distance;
            $farthest_points = array($start_point, $end_point); // Or whatever
        }
    }
}
```